# How can I get the value of the textbox from one page to several pages?

Tags: php, html, forms, post

How can I get the value of the `textbox` from one page to several pages lets take this example:

```
<form action = "next.php" method = "post">
    <input type = "text" name = "txtname">
    <input type = "submit" name = "btnSubmit">
</form>
```

Automatically if wish to get the value of the textbox named `txtname` on `next.php` i can surely get it because the action is `next.php`, but how if i want to see it on other php files?

Comment: Once the form is submitted store the text field value as `session` or as `cookie`.

Comment: use method="get" ?? to receive it in multiple files, ofcourse use session

Comment: Why don't you insert value in session variables. You can get value everywhere you want in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You may either:

Store it in a session variable on `next.php`:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['txtname'] = $_POST['txtname'];
```

You can then use this value in other pages simply by calling `session_start()` at the beginning of the page and then

```
echo "Text Name: ".$_SESSION['txtname'];
```

- Pass it via the `$_GET` parameter along the pages.
- Use cookies to store the variable locally and retrieve it when needed.

Comment: you should verify these values exist (isset) and escape special characters with htmlspecialchars()

Comment: I like you for being security conscious but this is outside the scope of what OP's asked.

Comment: Actually, you can't separate site web developement from the security point of view. The best is to consider it from the beginning

Comment: I agree with you. I try and take every precaution I take when developing an application. But, then, I'd say again. It is not what the OP has asked for.

Answer (score 0):

**METHOD 1 : Using Session**

**next.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['txtname']))
{
     $_SESSION['txtname'] = $_POST['txtname'];
}
```

**anyother.php**

```
if(isset($_SESSION['txtname']))
{
  echo $_SESSION['txtname'];
}
```

**Note :** use line `session_start();` on the top of the page where you want to access session.

**METHOD 2 : Using Cookie**

**next.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['txtname']))
{
    set_cookie("txtname", $_POST['txtname']);
}
```

**anyother.php**

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['txtname']))
{
  echo $_COOKIE['txtname'];
}
```

Comment: You should do isset in another.php too, and use htmlspecialchars on the post value